# Swap Windows 8 (or 10) Editions

Tags: windows, windows-8

I have two machines, one running Windows 8.1 Home (or Core) 64-bit and the other running Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit. I'd like to eventually install Windows 10 on each. But what I'd really like to accomplish is switching editions between the machines. I'd like the running Home to be running Pro, and vice versa.

I figured I could just try swapping keys only with slmgr /upk and /ipk, but that didn't work. I got an error when trying to install the key from the pro machine (that had been uninstalled) into the home machine. I quickly reinstalled each machine's own keys and all was well.

I suspect I can try a Windows AnyTime Upgrade to switch the Home machine into a Pro machine, but is there such a thing as a AnyTime Downgrade ?!

I'm trying to avoid uninstalling and reinstalling. I'm sure that would work, but would involve unbelievable hassles.

Perhaps as part of Windows 10 upgrade I could switch editions?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You are not going to be able to do this without clean installations on the machines of Windows 8.1.  You can only do that if they are retail licenses, oem licenses are tied to the machine.  You cannot go from Windows 8.1 Professional to Windows 8.1 Core without doing a reinstall.  While you can upgrade Core to Professional you can only do that with the Media Pack.